# Upgrading to AngularJS 1.3 from 1.2.6 unit test errors

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've been trying to upgrade our AngularJS app from 1.2.6 to 1.3.5 but have consistently been getting errors when trying to run the tests and the errors occur at test initialization. Further investigation proves that the tests are not even hit at the insertion points, rather fail just after initialization.

We are using Jasmine 1.x and karma test runner with Chrome as the browser. We are also using grunt to initiate the tests in this sequence:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', function () {
    console.log(config);
    grunt.task.run([
        'jsbeautifier',
        'newer:jshint',
        'clean:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'replace:htmlcommon',
        'replace:htmlenv',
        'replace:jscommon',
        'replace:jsenv',
        'to_single_quotes',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);
});
```

Here is the error log:

```
LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR                                     
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/devUser/Development/WebAppGroup/webapp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:25917
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR                                   
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/devUser/Development/WebAppGroup/webapp/app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-     
    resource.js:8
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR                                   
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/devUser/Development/WebAppGroup/webapp/app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-
    sanitize.js:8
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR                                   
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/devUser/Development/WebAppGroup/webapp/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-
    route.js:26
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.10.1): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.391 secs / 0 secs)
```

Excerpt of dependencies form our karma config file:

```
  'app/scripts/common/googlemaps.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/momentjs/moment.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.js',
  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-adobe.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-chartbeat.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-flurry.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-ga.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-gtm.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-kissmetrics.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-mixpanel.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-piwik.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-scroll.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-segmentio.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-splunk.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-woopra.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-marketo.js',
  'app/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
  'app/bower_components/ng-clip/src/ngClip.js',
  'app/bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js',
```

**UPDATED** Here is the entire karma config file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '',

// testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'ng-scenario'],
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/scripts/common/googlemaps.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/momentjs/moment.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.js',
  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-adobe.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-chartbeat.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-flurry.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-ga-cordova.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-ga.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-gtm.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-kissmetrics.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-mixpanel.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-piwik.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-scroll.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-segmentio.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-splunk.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-woopra.js',
  'app/bower_components/angularitics/src/angulartics-marketo.js',
  'app/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
  /*      'app/bower_components/ng-clip/src/ngClip.js',
  'app/bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js',*/
  'app/scripts/directives/setup.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: ['Chrome'],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false,
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
preprocessors: {
  'app/scripts/**/*.js': ['coverage']
}
});

};
```

Basically upon installing all the dependencies via bower, bower complains that several of the dependencies don't agree with AngularJS 1.3.x, but rather it needs 1.2.x where x = minor version required by individual dependency. I've tried doing the 'majority rules' take and given 1.2.27 (where most of the dependencies were asking for that particular version) and I've tried brute force 1.3.5 upgrade.

As a last resort, I've also applied the '*' to the dependency in my bower.json file to get the latest version of each dependency to use with AngularJS 1.3.5, however this doesn't work as well.

The feature set works as I can start my angular app and work through most of the features, but when it comes to ur BDD tests, this fails.

I'm stuck at this point as I've tried all possible paths. I think this issue has something related to the extensive set of libraries we are using and it's individual requirements for an older version of AngularJS. Also, why is it trying to load AngularJS more than once? I've read up on this being a possibility due to bad or missing routes but our routes work well when the application is started up.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: can you post your whole karma file?

Comment: I just posted it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? I seem to be having a similar issue.